# Why not an `instance?` word?

Tags: object, instance, factor-lang

Many object-aware scripting languages have an operator or function to test if an object is an instantiation of a given tuple or type. JavaScript has the `instanceof` operator, Python has an `isinstance` builtin as well as an `issubclass` builtin, etc.

But in Factor, all tuple classes and object types are given their own `instance?` word:

```
TUPLE: car speed ;
! autogenerated is the word car?, which tests if something is a car
TUPLE: boat weight ; 
! autogenerated is the word boat?, which tests if something is a boat
100 boat boa boat? ! -> t
100 boat boa car?  ! -> f
```

Boats are boats and cars are cars. Cars are not boats.

We could rephrase the last two lines like:

```
100 boat boa boat instance-of? ! -> t
100 boat boa car  instance-of? ! -> f
```

Instead, every object in Factor has its own specialised `instance?` word. Is this just for brevity and readability, or is there an implementation reason?

Would one want to customise the `instance?` word on certain objects for some reason? We have generics for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `instance-of?` would work most of the time:

```
: instance-of? ( obj cls -- ? ) [ class-of ] dip class<= ;
123 boat boa boat instance-of? .
t
123 boat boa tuple instance-of? .
t
123 fixnum instance-of? . 
t
```

But it is not good enough for more complicated types:

```
QUALIFIED: math.primes 
PREDICATE: even < integer 2 mod 0 = ;    
PREDICATE: prime < integer math.primes:prime? ;
7 prime? .
t
6 even?
t
7 prime instance-of?
f
6 even instance-of? .
f
```

The other reason is optimization. Words like `fixnum?`, `string?` and `array?` that are used in performance sensitive code are much easier to make fast than a more general `instance-of?` word.